# Cannot read property '_router' of undefined Vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I am trying to redirect and pass data from one component to another using `vue-router`.

In my main component I have a click link where I am calling a JavaScript function to do the routing.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" @click="switchComponent('ToolDetail')">click here</a>

methods: {
   switchComponent(comp) {
   this.$router.push({name:comp});
},
```

As of now the routing itself is giving console error when the link is clicked.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_router' of undefined

In my main.js I have already imported my router-

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from 'vue-router'

Vue.config.productionTip = false
export const changeRoute = new Vue();
new Vue({
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')

Vue.use(router)
```

**Edit:**
Based on answer from @ittus, I did something like this-

In my main.js-

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

In my `HomeContent.vue`-

```
<template>
    ...
    ..
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" @click="switchComponent('ToolDetail')">click here</a>
    ...
    ..
</template>
<script>
import ToolDetail from './ToolDetail.vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';

...
..

methods: {
   switchComponent(comp) {
      const routes = [
        { path: '/ToolDetail', component: ToolDetail, name: 'ToolDetail' }
      ]
      const router = new VueRouter({
        routes
      })
      router.push({name:'ToolDetail'});
  },

...
..
</script>
```

Now, when I click the link nothing happens and no console error.
Any help with this please? Let me know if I can provide more details.

Comment: Are you sure - HomeContent.vue exporting this in App.vue file ?, also make sure you are using `export` in HomeContent.vue correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass `router` data to Vue component

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'

Vue.config.productionTip = false
export const changeRoute = new Vue();

Vue.use(Router) // should place it before new Vue()

// just example
const router = new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'ToolDetail',
      component: ToolDetail // place your component here
    }
  ]
})

new Vue({
  router,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

You can check more details in [Getting Started document](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/#html)

Comment: My `App.vue` is the main component which will load other components. Also, I am importing the `vue-rouer` in my `main.js` which has the `new Vue({..})`. How can import `ToolDetail` component and create the `routes: []` based on that?

Comment: Updated the post based on your answer. Please check.

Comment: You need to set up routers in `main.js` component, not in `HomeContent.vue`. Not that in `main.js`, you need to pass `router`:
`new Vue({
  router,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')`